# Django: Create a queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a Friendship model which looks like this:

```
from_user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='friends')
to_user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='friends_')
```

I have a manager to get all the Friendship models of a user:

```
def for_user(self, user):
    return self.filter( Q(to_user=user) | Q(from_user=user) )
```

So now I would like to have a queryset with all the user objects that are friends. I thought of just writing a simple loop and add them to a list but then I lose the ability to write queries. For example for all the friends of a user I would like to filter/get one with a particular username.

The title of my question is a little generic so if anybody knows a better one feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.objects.filter(Q(friends__to_user=someuser)|Q(friends___from_user=someuser))
```

No clue if that second `Q()` will actually work, but that's what you've decided to call the related field.

Comment: No, the Django ORM will do the right thing if it's a `User`. If you *do* have the PK then just add `_id` at the end.